# I need date other way round

Tags: php, mysqli

I have this at present;

```
if ( (isset($_GET['future'])) && ($_GET['future'] == '1') )
{
    $future = 'AND shows.show_date > CURDATE()';
    $urlparam = '&future=1';
} else
{
    $future = 'AND shows.show_date <= CURDATE()';
    $urlparam = '';
}
```

However, I need it to list my item from nearest date any idea?

Comment: we don't have enough information to help you. what's the problem? what's your question?

Comment: At present this code lists future dog shows that I have in my database, however, it lists them at present with the furthest away dated show at top. I need to change it to list them so that the nearest dated show at top. Hope this helps

Comment: so, you want _order_ the dataset by date? you can do it with `ORDER BY shows.show_date ASC`

Comment: Thanks Federkun 1

Answer (score 0):

Change your mysqli query to get *the nearest dated show at top.* Use:

```
ORDER BY your-date-field ASC
```